# How to view the source code of a .mex file

Tags: matlab, mex

I saw online that you can just use `edit rgb2gray` to open up the source file, but I ran into another function in the `rgb2gray.m` file that I don't know how to view.

Lines 54-55 contain the following function:

```
if threeD
  I = images.internal.rgb2graymex(X);
```

How do I view the source code for this `rgb2graymex` function?

Comment: Are you mainly interested in what algorithm they used to convert it? Also, if you're really interested. There's a good chance that it is not contained within a mex file in older versions of Matlab. So if you are able to download a version from say 2006 there's a good chance you'll be able to get the source code from there.

Comment: Yes, I just need to see which transform matrix they use. They document it as being `Y = 0.2989 * R + 0.5870 * G + 0.1140 * B` but after running the calculations manually and comparing results against the rgb to gray function equivalents in the Pillow and Numpy Python libraries, that doesn't seem to be the case. I believe that there is some weird rounding involved

Comment: And unfortunately, I don't have access to that old of a Matlab version. Good idea/hack though

Comment: Try running a pure red, pure green, and pure blue image through it which should give you the coefficients. Another thing to note is that the image that you are converting is probably uint-8 which will give you considerable rounding error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can't see the contents of a `.mex` file, as @Adriaan indicates in his answer.

You mention in the comments, though, that what you really want is to find the coefficients used from the transform matrix for converting RGB to grayscale. You can find these in the code immediately below the section you quote:

```
  T    = inv([1.0 0.956 0.621; 1.0 -0.272 -0.647; 1.0 -1.106 1.703]);
  coef = T(1,:);
```

That gives me:

```
coef =
   0.298936021293775   0.587043074451121   0.114020904255103
```

Now it's true that you can't demonstrate conclusively that the `.mex` file is doing the same thing as this; but the `.mex` file is just there to speed things up when you pass in a big mxnx3 RGB image, rather than a small nx3 RGB colormap. I'd be very surprised if it was using different coefficients. A few experiments that I've just done indicate only the tiniest of numerical differences (<1e-15) between the `.mex` file and using the coefficients present in the code.

Comment: What purpose is the `T    = inv([1.0 0.956 0.621; 1.0 -0.272 -0.647; 1.0 -1.106 1.703]);`?

Comment: Yeah this does bring the results much closer to Matlab's. Thanks for noticing and letting me know!

Comment: @Durkee The full array is for converting NTSC (Y,I,Q) values to RGB values. See `doc ntsc2rgb` from Image Processing Toolbox for details. To convert RGB to NTSC you use the inverse of that matrix. The first NTSC component (Y) is the same as grayscale, so the code is using the first row only. It looks like the developer found it more convenient to put the full matrix in the code, invert it on the fly, and extract the relevant coefficients, rather than precomputing the coefficients. You could probably speed up `rgb2gray` a tiny amount by doing this.

Answer (score 4):

`rgb2graymex` is, as its name suggests, a .mex file. .mex files are pre-compiled files which you thus cannot view the contents of, unless you use exotic decompilers (which usually don't give a 100% result), or obtain the source code from the one who's written it, which is not going to happen with proprietary code.

Read more on MEX files [on the MathWorks site](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/introducing-mex-files.html).